# Allow minus sign only as first input

Tags: angularjs, regex, input, numeric

I'm using a regex to my numeric inputs to allow only numbers and a comma, but now I wanted to add the chance of negative numbers, which could be done like this `text.replace(/[^0-9,-]/g, '');`.

However, I'd like to allow the minus sign only as the very first input in order to avoid things like `1-3,7`.

Comment: What about `^-?\d+$` for integers, alternatively `^-?[\,d]+$` for commata in thousands.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend just using string `test()` here, with an appropriate regex pattern:

```
^-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

You may simply reject any input which fails to pass this regex.  This makes more sense than trying to do a replacement on the input, since not all inputs would be salvageable anyway.

Examples:

```js
var pass1 = 123.456;
var pass2 = -999;
var pass3 = '123,456,789.888';
var fail = '1-3,7';
console.log(/^-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(pass1));
console.log(/^-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(pass2));
console.log(/^-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(pass3));
console.log(/^-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(fail));
```

A brief explanation of what the pattern does:

```
^                from the start of the string
    -?           match an optional negative sign
    \d{1,3}      match one to three digits
    (?:,\d{3})*  followed by a thousands term (, + 3 digits) zero or more times
    (?:\.\d+)?   followed by an optional decimal component
$                end of the string
```

Comment: I have to make the replace since this regex is inside a condition, associated to a variable and depending on the case, it'll be slightly different. What I'm using right now is `valueMatch = text.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');` allowing only numbers and dot and another one allowing numbers and a comma; I tried `text.replace(/^-?[^0-9,]/g, '');` but it rejects minus as first input and I want to accept minus only as first input

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, this is not the best approach.  I vote for using a single regex pattern to _validate_ your inputs.  Don't bother trying to fix others' mistakes.